# In ASP.NET , how can you make AJAX calls consistently to the same url?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So I have an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Home/GetFullView",
    success: function (data) {
    $("#sched").html(data);
    },
    fail: function () {
    }
 });
```

Where "Home" is the controller and "GetFullView" is the action.  Sometimes the call works.  However sometimes it crashes the application because it tries this url: "Home/Home/GetFullView".  So it's adding "home" once too many times.

How can I consistently have it check the same url without doubling the "Home" controller name?

If I simply use url: "GetFullView" it also crashes because it looks for "Home" controller.

Comment: Try "~/Home/GetFullView"

Comment: Does your code get called from within a page on the the home controller?  If so, it will use site relative url... thus Home/Home/...  ad a preceding / before Home so it's /Home

Comment: Adding just "/" seemed to do the trick.  Adding "~" actually didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a leading `/`

```
url: "/Home/GetFullView",
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a `local url` like:

`url: "/Home/GetFullView"`

Answer (score 0):

To get your relative path fully qualified, use this:

```
url: "~/Home/GetFullView"
```

This will then give you the right qualified path whether you are at the website or application level.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev It most certainly works in MVC on the client side.

Comment: He didn't mention he was using MVC. Even though MVC may appropriately transform a URL when it wasn't explicitly used in Razor syntax, it is, in my opinion, confusing. You can also technically build a Web Forms server tag in plain text in JavaScript and it will be rendered "correctly" (as in, the server tag will be rendered as a normal HTML Tag) but that doesn't make it a good practice or clear to the developer.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Actually I use the same syntax in static HTML embedded in an MVC application for certain resources such as images and yes, Ajax calls.  It has nothing specifically to do with MVC.  I just happen to have used it in am MVC application.  For the OP's question, it works just fine.

Comment: It actually didn't work for the OP. And if you use that outside an ASP.NET MVC site, it isn't going to work (not in Web Forms on non-server controls, or anywhere else), hence my opinion of it being confusing.

Comment: To quote the MSDN: "You can use the ~ operator in any path-related property in server controls. The ~ operator is recognized only for server controls and in server code. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements."

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Fair enough.  I hadn't seen the OP's comment.  I stand corrected :)

Comment: Yeah I'm not trying to be a pest.  If you say it works for you, I believe you. Like I mentioned, I've (in testing) built a server control in front-end JavaScript in Web Forms, and it rendered correctly. For the life of me I can't figure out why ASP.NET made that even possible... and why the server is parsing my JavaScript strings lol.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I'm definitely using it for statically linked images in raw HTML and it works just fine.  In fact I _had_ to use it or it didn't work properly when I just used `/`.  Sometimes just weird stuff happens :)